# UiTextView doesn't display text on iphone os 2.0

Tags: iphone, text, uitextview, operating-system

My text view shows the text when i am using iphone OS 3.0-
but for some reason it will not show the text on OS 2.0.
I can get the inputed text on OS 2.0 and even save it to file,
and then restore the text but still- the text is not visible on OS 2.0.
I have tried changing the scrolling properties and the font and the color and the hidden property -
Anybody have an idea what it is?
Thanks-
Nir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:
I added my text view to a button view-
so i changed it and now I am adding it to a uiView.

I guess there is a different way for displaying a text field on top of a button in the old OS 2.0.